# Custom Nested serializer and lookups

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a Category model and a Menu Model and I want to display the JSON data as follows:

```
{
   "category":{
      "category": "Something",
      "menu": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "dish": "Sample Dish",
                    "price": 150,
                    "restaurant": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "dish": "Sample Dish",
                    "price": 150,
                    "restaurant": 1
                },
              }

}
```

Here are the models:

```py
class Menu(models.Model):
    dish = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Menu_Category',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='menu')
    price = models.IntegerField()
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='menu')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dish

class Menu_Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Menu Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Menu Categories'
```

and here is the seriailizer:

```py
class MenuSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields =['dish','price','restaurant']

class MenuCategorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    menu = MenuSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Menu_Category
        fields = ['category','menu']
```

I have tried building up some custom nested serializers as well and cant seem to get the JSON data right.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by creating the property on the category model that returns it's related menus. Just FYI(You can also use `self.menu_set.all()`). See below for the model change

```
class Menu_Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Menu Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Menu Categories'

    @property
    def menu(self):
        return Menu.objects.filter(category=self)
```

In the serializer, change the serializer inheritence to `ModelSerializer`. You shouldn't need to change anything else unless your property name in models.py is different to the serializer fieldname

[Sources in Rest framework serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

```
class MenuCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menu = MenuSerializer(read_only=True,many=True, source='menu') # -- Source must be the same as declared in models.py property

    class Meta:
        model = Menu_Category
        fields = ['category','menu']
```

Comment: we can use reverse relationships instead writing a property to it.

Comment: you can. It's all preference.

Comment: I mean to say you are replicating the functionality without enhancing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `id` to `MenuSerializer` fields and you can use reverse relation `menu_set` with `source` parameter in serializer like below

```py
class MenuSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields =['id', 'dish','price','restaurant']

class MenuCategorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    menu = MenuSerializer(read_only=True,many=True, source='menu_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Menu_Category
        fields = ['category','menu']
```